# What is, in the most general sense, a geodesic line?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations

So, in a sphere a geodesic is just a section of the great circle containing 2 points, such that that is the smallest possible segment.

My focus right now is mostly on ellipsoids, but ideally I want to understand what is the mathematical definition. In essence I want, given a 2D manifold, a the definition of the geodesic line for that manifold.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know what a metric is?

Comment: No "smallest possible segment." All the great circles are geodesics on a sphere. Geodesics are only required to be *locally* distance-minimizing.

Comment: B. Pasternak, no I do not. I am not even a mathematician, I am a computer scientist :p

Comment: Ted Shifrin, that's not true, in any great circle there are 2 segments of the circle that connect 2 points, the geodesic is the shortest of those 2 lines.

Comment: @Makogan: those 2 "lines" are both geodesics. The shortest is the *minimizing* geodesic.

Comment: Oh ok, I c, thank you

Comment: On a circular cone as another example you see several geodesics connecting 2 given end points. There is a finite number of Clairaut constants for each of them, each supplying a solution to a boundary value problem with differeny boundary conditions. The minimum among them is "the" geodesic.